# spamtrap find sites

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

How can I find any site with spamtrap email?
I'd like to find a normal site with 1 or more traps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Telling people where spamtrap websites are sort of defeats the point of having them in the first place. If crawlers picking up email address could avoid certain spam traps their effectiveness is destroyed

Comment: I want to find the EXAMPLE of such pages

Answer (score 0):

http://www.projecthoneypot.org/

( No, this answer is not useless, the home page uses their own honeyopot techniques, so it's a fitting double-face example. :V )

Comment: I haven't found any emails in this html :(

Comment: Pydev, it's not an e-mail link. Look near the end of the file.